# Crystal Report Parameter Link to Sub Report with Command field

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a main Crystal report which consists of several sub-reports, I managed to link the parameter from main report to sub-report by following this simple steps:

1. create a parameter `ParamOP` in main report
2. insert a sub-report in the main report
3. right click on sub-report > Change sub report links
4. select the parameter `ParamOP` from the "Available fields" window and add to "Fields to link to"
5. you will notice it will be automatically populated in the "Subreport parameter fields to use" link it to the sub-report field, then click OK

Now, since my sub-report has a command field, **how can I display the record in sub-report using the parameter?**

Here's my SQL query inside the command, however no data was displayed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CONFORMEREPORTS 
WHERE COVERAGEHEADER = '{Pm-?paramOP}'
ORDER BY [LINENO] ASC
```

[image]

Comment: try creating same parameter in subreport in `SQL command` and while linking sub report and main report link this parameter of main report to same parameter of the sub report.

Comment: Thanks siva it works, you always help me. now i have another problem, i have multiple parameter in different sub-report, how can i pass this in CR programmatically?

Comment: where do you want to pass the parameters? I mean pass to main report... need more explanation

Comment: @Siva Hello Siva, you should post your answer as an answer and the OP should accept it, thanks ;)